# Crash While running Pushgp using SBCL 1.1.6.0-3c5581a on mac OS X Yosemite Ver. 10.10.3

Tags: macos, garbage-collection, sbcl

The following error message occured While running Pushgp using SBCL 1.1.6.0-3c5581a on mac OS X Yosemite Ver. 10.10.3, what do i do next to correct it and avoid future occurrence? Thanks

```html
Producing next generation...
Heap exhausted during garbage collection: 48 bytes available, 80 requested.
 Gen StaPg UbSta LaSta LUbSt Boxed Unboxed LB   LUB  !move  Alloc  Waste   Trig    WP  GCs Mem-age
   0:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0        0     0  5368709    0   0  0.0000
   1:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0        0     0  5368709    0   0  0.0000
   2:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0        0     0  5368709    0   0  0.0000
   3:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0        0     0  5368709    0   0  0.0000
   4: 90540 90458     0     0 16653 42019  3720   930     0 257732888 1634024  2000000    0   0  1.0370
   5:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0        0     0  2000000    0   0  0.0000
   6:     0     0     0     0  5615  1269     0     0     0 28196864     0  2000000 5549   0  0.0000
   Total bytes allocated    = 533559232
   Dynamic-space-size bytes = 536870912
GC control variables:
   *GC-INHIBIT* = true
   *GC-PENDING* = in progress
fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 776:
Heap exhausted, game over.

Welcome to LDB, a low-level debugger for the Lisp runtime environment.
ldb>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your running out of memory is not caused by a larger problem, you might just be able to run sbcl with a larger dynamic space size, *e.g.*

```
sbcl --dynamic-space-size 2048
```